# XAMPP on macOS - mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root! [ERROR] Aborting

Tags: xampp

Today XAMPP on macOS Monterey will not start mySQL.

The error log shows:

> 2021-12-20 12:44:37 25199 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with
> databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql Warning:
> World-writable config file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf'
> is ignored 2021-12-20 12:44:37 0 [Note]
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.21-MariaDB)
> starting as process 25273 ... 2021-12-20 12:44:37 0 [Warning] Setting
> lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld: Please consult the
> Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root! 2021-12-20
> 12:44:37 0 [ERROR] Aborting 2021-12-20 12:44:37 25199 mysqld_safe
> mysqld from pid file
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Mandoes-Mac-mini.local.pid
> ended

Answer (score 3):

- Open Terminal
- Navigate to the XAMPP config folder

  ```
  cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/
  ```
- Set permissions of `my.cnf` to `600`

  ```
  sudo chmod 600 my.cnf
  ```
- Restart MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove read/write access from Admin & Everyone, and keep read/write access for System only.